# javascript last if statement always read

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement

I'm using angularjs as the framework to write a small quiz. I wrote 4 `if` statements. But for some unexplained reason, the last condition is always read even though none of the conditions/answers has been chosen.

The `$scope.makeup` always shows `You should have makeup Four`, why?

Shouldn't an `if` statement be overlooked if no condition is met in it, yet?

```
var silverMetal = ($scope.userChoices.metal === 'silver');
var goldMetal = ($scope.userChoices.metal === 'gold');

var greenTone = ($scope.userChoices.tone === 'green');
var blueTone = ($scope.userChoices.tone === 'blue');

var greyBlueBlackEye = ($scope.userChoices.eye === 'grey' || 'blue' || 'black');
var greenHazelBrownEye = ($scope.userChoices.eye === 'green' || 'hazel' || 'brown');

var lightblondeGingerDarkblondeHair = ($scope.userChoices.hair === 'light blonde' || 'ginger' || 'dark blonde');
var lightbrownDarkbrownBlackHair = ($scope.userChoices.hair === 'light brown' || 'dark brown' || 'black');


if (silverMetal && greenTone && greyBlueBlackEye && lightblondeGingerDarkblondeHair) {
  $scope.makeup = 'You should have makeup One';
}

if (silverMetal && greenTone && greyBlueBlackEye && lightbrownDarkbrownBlackHair) {
  $scope.makeup = 'You should have makeup Two';
}

if (silverMetal && greenTone && greenHazelBrownEye && lightblondeGingerDarkblondeHair) {
  $scope.makeup = 'You should have makeup Three';
}

if (silverMetal && greenTone && greenHazelBrownEye && lightbrownDarkbrownBlackHair) {
  $scope.makeup = 'You should have makeup Four';
}
```

Comment: `$scope.userChoices.eye === 'grey' || 'blue' || 'black'` does not do what you think it does. The `||` operator cannot be factorized that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the lines like this:

`var greyBlueBlackEye = ($scope.userChoices.eye === 'grey' || 'blue' || 'black');`

A string like 'blue' is truthy, so this is evaluated as `($scope.userChoices.eye === 'grey') || true`, and so evaluates as true. You'll need to do your comparisons separately, or check if the value is in an array containing 'grey', 'blue', and 'black'

Comment: Thanks @StephenTG, for the solution. It works comparing seperately. Didn't even think of that even though I know the rules. I guess that's what happens with lack of sleep because of coding. Thanks again.